# Can you get from Frankfurt Flughafen to Frankfurt City during a railway strike (Dec 8 2023)?

Tags: trains, public-transport, event-based-effects, frankfurt, fra

I'm scheduled to arrive in FRA airport in about 3 hours and need to get to the city for the night. The German Railway (Bahn) is on strike and it seems like chaos has ensued; it's very difficult to get reliable information of what is still working. Earlier in the day it looked like the S-Bahn was still running, but now it looks like most trains are cancelled. Hauptbahnhof would be great but anything close to city center/Messe or within working public transit would be great!

I'd appreciate input from anyone who is currently on the ground there and has some visibility to what's actually happening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Local transport (U-Bahn, Bus, Tram) is still running.

Bus 61: *Frankfurt (Main) Flughafen Terminal 1* to *Frankfurt (Main) Südbahnhof*

- [61 Route: Fahrpläne, Haltestellen & Karten - Frankfurt (Main) Flughafen Terminal 1 (Aktualisiert)](https://moovitapp.com/index/de/%C3%96PNV-line-61-Mainz-4409-3618869-112406106-0)

From there to the Hauptbahnhof (or elsewhere within the city center) should be no problem with the local Busses or Trams.

---

> - [RMV.DE - Warnstreik: GDL lässt Bahnen bundesweit stillstehen](https://www.rmv.de/c/de/informationen-zum-rmv/der-rmv/rmv-aktuell/warnstreik-gdl-laesst-bahnen-bundesweit-stillstehen)
>
> **Fahrtalternativen nutzen**
> Frankfurt: **U-Bahnen, Straßenbahnen und städtische Buslinien nicht vom Streik betroffen**
> U-Bahnen und Straßenbahnen sowie der städtische Busverkehr in Frankfurt sind nicht vom Streik betroffen. Alle Frankfurter Linien verkehren Donnerstag und Freitag nach Fahrplan.
>
> Die Verkehrsgesellschaft Frankfurt setzt am 7. und 8. Dezember ganztags bis Betriebsende längere Züge auf den U-Bahn-Linien U1, U2, U3, U6 und U8 ein.
>
> Auf der **Buslinie 61 zum Flughafen** sollen möglichst Gelenkbusse eingesetzt werden, da sie mehr Platz bieten.
>
> > **Use alternative travel options**
> > Frankfurt: **subways, trams and city bus lines not affected by the strike**
> > Subways and trams as well as city bus services in Frankfurt are not affected by the strike. All Frankfurt lines will run according to schedule on Thursday and Friday.
> >
> > The Frankfurt transport company will be using longer trains on the U1, U2, U3, U6 and U8 subway lines all day on December 7th and 8th until the end of operations.
> >
> > Articulated buses should be used on the **bus line 61 to the airport** if possible, as they offer more space.

Comment: That worked (mostly). When  arrived, trains were still running sporadically but since my flight was late, I missed all of these. The bus sort-of worked. Bus 61 was not a gelenkbus and the driver went out of his way to strand as many passengers as possible: He parked in the wrong spot, kept the doors closed until the very last minute and refused to ask any questions. All passengers that were waiting at the correct spot got stranded: when the driver saw them come running, he left as quickly as possible.

Comment: To complement the list:  You could also take bus 62 to Schwanheim or 58/X58 to Höchst and change to the tram there. (In Höchst a short walk or a hop on another bus is needed).

Answer (score 1):

Taking a taxi is another alternative. Note that during a train strike demand for taxis will be significantly higher than usual. As the strike is announced beforehand supply might be slightly higher than usual. Prices are fixed, so you won't pay extra in a situation like that. Hence one has to expect long waiting times to get a taxi. And even at the regular price taxis are not cheap.